# Div circular scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Have one `div`:

[image]

Here's what scrolling of this `div` should look like:

[image]

The only way I see is to duplicate `div` to left and right sides of original one, and then scroll the whole bunch. Here is a corner-cutting implementation sketch: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7ofp6q9/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $original = $("#original");
  // Duplicate div to the left and right of original
  $original.clone().attr("id", "left").prependTo("#scroll");
  $original.clone().attr("id", "right").appendTo("#scroll");

  // Set according width to parent we are going to scroll
  w = $original.width();
  $scroll = $("#scroll");
  $scroll.width(w * 3);

  // Radio button
  $left_rb = $("#left_rb");

  function roll_it() {
    dest_pos = 0;
    // Check radion button
    if ($left_rb.prop("checked")) dest_pos = -2 * w;
    // Set start position
    $scroll.css('left', -w + 'px');
    // Roll it
    $scroll.animate({
      left: dest_pos + "px"
    }, 1000, "linear", roll_it);
  }

  roll_it();
});
```

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
#container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#scroll {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="scroll">
    <div class="scrollable" id="original">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvcpe.gif" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Direction:</p>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="direction" value="left" id="left_rb" checked>&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;
  <input type="radio" name="direction" value="rigth" id="rigt_rb">&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;</form>
```

Any better way? Existing plugins (it should be scrollable to any choosen position, not just slideshow)?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to localize all of your variables using `var`.

JavaScript naming using `interCaps` is more idiomatic than `under_scores`.

For a better user experience, use `<label>` tags on your radio buttons.  That makes the ">>>>>" text part of the control, for a larger click target.

If you are willing to change the semantically significant `<img>` tag into a purely decorative `background-image`, then the code can be greatly simplified through the use of [`background-repeat: repeat-x`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-repeat).

```js
$(function() {
  var $scroll = $(".scrollable");
  var w = $scroll.width();
  var pos = 0;

  // Radio button
  var $left_rb = $("#left_rb");

  function rollIt() {
    var movement = $left_rb.prop("checked") ? -w : w;
    pos += movement;

    $scroll.animate({
      backgroundPosition: pos + "px"
    }, 1000, "linear", rollIt);
  }

  rollIt();
});
```

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#scroll {
  background-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/vvcpe.gif);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollable" id="scroll"></div>
<p>Direction:</p>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="direction" value="left" id="left_rb" checked>&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="direction" value="right">&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was overall hard to read. But it is somewhat structured properly.

**Let's analyse Javascript!**

1. Are you afraid of `var`s?

   Yeah, you don't use a single `var`. **EVERYTHING** is a global variable.

   Why is it bad? You are polluting an already polluted object, you allow outside code to mess with your code and it is slower to access global variables than local variables (it's around 10x slower).

   Please, use `var`s.
2. Your variable names are not that good.

   Some are short, cryptic, meaningless.

   Names like `w` and `dest_pos` don't help much. What's `w`? Can you figure it just by the name?
3. Misuse of the library.

   Why do you have this:

   ```
   $original = $("#original");
   $original.clone().attr("id", "left").prependTo("#scroll");
   $original.clone().attr("id", "right").appendTo("#scroll");
   ```

   When you can write:

   ```
   var $original = $("#original");
   var $scroll = $("#scroll");
   $original.clone().prependTo($scroll);
   $original.clone().appendTo($scroll);
   ```

   The `id` isn't being used and you can store `#scroll` in a variable (as you do a few lines after).
4. More library misuse.

   jQuery has something really great going on for it: chaining methods.

   You did it everywhere, except there:

   ```
   $scroll.css('left', -w + 'px');
   // Roll it
   $scroll.animate({
     left: dest_pos + "px"
   }, 1000, "linear", roll_it);
   ```

   You should write it on this way:

   ```
   $scroll
       .css('left', -w + 'px')
       .animate({
           left: dest_pos + "px"
       }, 1000, "linear", roll_it);
   ```
5. Hidden dangers!

   Lets analyse this line:

   ```
   if ($left_rb.prop("checked")) dest_pos = -2 * w;
   ```

   Please, don't eat away your braces.

   Remember the [Apple SSL Bug](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/)? It was all caused because someone repeated a line after an `if` without braces. Like yours.

   Please, use braces.
6. Mixed quotes.

   Even though it only happened once, you have to check your quotes.

   Pick between single and double quotes and use the same style, from the beggining to the end of the document.

---

With all those changes, this is how I would write your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $original = $("#original");
    var $scroll = $("#scroll");
    $original.clone().prependTo($scroll);
    $original.clone().appendTo($scroll);

    var original_width = $original.width();
    $scroll.width(original_width * 3);

    var $left_rb = $("#left_rb");

    function roll_it () {

        var scroll_by = 0;

        if ($left_rb.prop("checked")) {
            scroll_by = -2 * original_width;
        }

        $scroll
            .css('left', -original_width + "px")
            .animate({
                left: scroll_by + "px"
            }, 1000, "linear", roll_it);
    }

    roll_it();
});
```

Comment: `w` and `dest_pos` seemed obvious enough to me. I also don't see any danger with omitting braces if it's a short statement _on the same line_ as the `if`.

Comment: @200_success Apple didn't too...

Comment: The key difference is _on the same line_. [Apple's `goto` statements](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html) were on their own lines.

Comment: @200_success Correct. Because the lines were too big.

Comment: `var roll_it = function() { … }` and `function roll_it() { … }` have exactly the same scope. The only difference is hoisting.

Comment: @200_success A quick experiments shows I screwed up. Fixed it. Thanks for the eye-opening warning